# check the style attributes of a div in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, html, coding-style

Just as the title says, i have a div in the aspx side which has ID and runat=server.
I have 2 functions in the vb.net side code, on of which adds style as div.style.add("display","none").
In the other function i want to check if the div style display is none or not. How can i check that programatically?

Answer (score 1):

got it. div.style.item("display"), will GET value of that item.